# infinite email loop with alias when auto responder is activated on destination email server

Tags: postfix

I have configured a postfix email alias from xxxx@mydomain.com to yyyy@anotherdomain.com (yyyy@anotherdomain.com is the mailbox of one of my customers) but the email server for yyyy@anotherdomain.com is configured with an auto-responder and send back a message to xxxx@mydomain.com. It result in an infinite message loop. Is there any way to be protected from such case (as i can't configure the mail servers of my customers) ?

for adding details: I use docker-mailserver and already posted my question to https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver/issues/1402